# State FIPS, county FIPS AND FIPS to latitude longitude?

Tags: r

I have a dataset looking like this, with 600 columns:

```
 COUNTY_NAME    STATE_NAME  STATE_FIPS  CNTY_FIPS   FIPS    Year
 Boone          Illinois    17          007         17007   2010
 Bureau         Illinois    17          011         17011   2008
 Champaign      Illinois    17          019         17019   2010
 Cook           Illinois    17          031         17031   2006
```

I need to get the centroids of smallest possible unit/area (counties?) for further analysis.

Is it possible to get this information in latitude longitude in R?

Comment: try [google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=fips%20shapefile&es_th=1); also, it's not clear you know what you want. for example, what CRS are you looking for?

Comment: `rgeos::gCentroid(rgdal::readOGR("http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json", "OGRGeoJSON"), byid=TRUE)` that gets you all the centroids for the US counties (you can expand it out and do `merge`/etc). It's lat/lon projection. If you just need Illinois a more targeted solution can be provided.