# How do I convert County FIPS to Lat-Long coordinates in R or Python?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, geo

Glyphosate has hogged the limelight recently due to listing as a possible carcinogen by the World Health Organization's IARC. I got curious about pesticide usage patterns in the US and plotting this data with interactive maps in R-Shiny, using leaflet, for example.

County-level estimates of pesticide usage can be found here: https://water.usgs.gov/nawqa/pnsp/usage/maps/county-level/

The data are reported using State/County FIPS codes. I require lat-long coordinates to show the data.

It seems possible to go from lat-long to FIPS quite easily, as illustrated by this API here: https://geo.fcc.gov/api/census/

How to go in the reverse direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868735/how-do-i-convert-from-census-fips-to-lat-lon or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846166/state-fips-county-fips-and-fips-to-latitude-longitude

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found required using a REST API from here.com of the five options (below). I first cross-referenced FIPS codes from USGS table with County and State names using table `fips_codes` from `library(tigris)`. This gave me names to put together in address lines, like `Boulder County, CO`. Next, I wrote a small function `here_now` with sample usage as:

```
here_now("Boulder+County,+CO") # $lat: 40.08791; $lon: -105.3447
```

Implementation is a call to the REST API using `fromJSON` from `library(jsonlite)`

```
here_now <- function(searchtext) {

    AppCode <- getOption("hereAppCode")
    AppID <- getOption("hereAppID")       

    rootURL <- "https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?"
    app_id = paste("app_id", AppID, sep="=")
    app_code = paste("app_code", AppCode, sep="=")
    searchtext = paste("searchtext", searchtext, sep="=")

    request <- paste(paste(rootURL, app_id, sep=''), app_code, searchtext, sep="&")
    response = fromJSON(request)

    res <- list()
    res$lat <- response$Response$View$Result[[1]]$Location$NavigationPosition[[1]]$Latitude
    res$lon <- response$Response$View$Result[[1]]$Location$NavigationPosition[[1]]$Longitude

    res
}
```

Further, I used the FCC's reverse geo-coding API to validate: https://geo.fcc.gov/api/census/

Options I experimented with for geocoding included:
- google APIs via ggmap (requires API key, requires credit card)
- mapquest API (requires API key, no credit card needed)
- Data Science Toolkit's RDSK implementation
- Geonames service via eponymous R package
- Here APIs (require AppID and AppCode, freemium model)